# Setting the hovered-over (not selected) list item in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, hover, flash-builder, flex-spark

I have three lists stuck together horizontally in Flex that I would like to act like columns of the same list. I've put a method on `change` to make the same index on all three lists in sync with each other when an item is selected in any list. I want to do the same for hover; that is, when you hover over an item and the light blue background appears, and I want the same index on the other two lists to also show that light blue background.

Is there a way to get and set the "hovered-over item" in a list, or create a visually analogous effect?

Comment: Would you be better off with a DataGrid?  I'm not sure what benefits you achieve by trying to get three Lists to act like a DataGrid with three columns.

Comment: I'd like these columns to have gaps between them, so they line up with blanks above them. I guess one way of solving this would be to come up with a more typical interface.

Comment: Can you specify a verticalSeparatorSkin style in order to widen the gap between columns? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#styleSummary